# Как подключить файлы библиотеки jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Включены в head. Но все равно скрипт slider не работает. Что то еще должно быть?

Comment: а основной `jquery` где? у вас `jquery-ui`

Comment: teran дело говорит =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>`